# php pdo: prepare() vs transactions

Tags: php, transactions, pdo, prepared-statement

Are `prepare()` and `transactions` mutually exclusive? I've got a lot of queries that I build and then execute, so it sounds like using a transaction is what I want; but I read on the [prepare.statment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) page that using the `bindParam` method eliminates SQL-injection. Is there some way to do both?

Here's an example of the code I have right now (which may or may not be correct):

```
$dbhost=FOO;
$dbuser=FOOBAR;
$dbpass=RABOOF;
$options=array(STUFF);

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
// I know this ^ works

$dbh->beginTransaction();
$record_data = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $db.$tbl SET :column=:value WHERE `key` = :key;");

function record_data($q,$a,$k){
    $record_data->bindParam(':column', $q);
    $record_data->bindParam(':value', $a);
    $record_data->bindParam(':key', $k);
    $record_data->execute();
}

// $pairs is an array with ~50 objects/rows
foreach($pairs as $pair){
    list($qstn , $ans) = explode('=', $pair);
    switch($qstn){
        case 1: if(something) record_data($qstn,$ans,$key); break;
        case 2: if(something) record_data($qstn,$ans,$key); break;
        case 3: if(something) record_data($qstn,$ans,$key); break;
        // more
        default: record_data($qstn,$ans,$key); break;
    }
}
$dbh->commit();
```

When I tried out the full code, I got `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.` Usually I see a message like that when my connection info is wrong (or the account isn't set up properly/as I expect). But I tested the PDO connection separately and it worked fine. So I probably did something else wrong.

**EDIT**: Are variables allowed in `prepare()`?

**EDIT 2**: I added `try{}` around the `$dbh = PDO(…)` and added `echo "connected"` at the end of the `try` (and did the catch bit), and it echo'd "connected", so it is connecting. But after "connected" it prints that error message, so the issue is happening after a successful connection.

**EDIT 3**: I added

```
$dbRS = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`table`;");
$row = empty($dbRS) ? false : $dbRS->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
```

and it printed the first row of the table, so for sure it's connecting.

Comment: Check your login stuff. I can say: Transactions and PreparedStatements work fine together

Comment: @KingCrunch: I'm sure the login info is correct (noted in the code)

Comment: There's no difference between preparing/executing a statement within a transaction and directly executing a query within the same transaction - in the end they're both just queries that get executed. prepared statements can simply be reused with much less overhead than executing a 'new' statement each time.

Comment: @MarcB : ah, okay thanks. Any idea why I'm getting that error message? Since I already checked the login, all I can think of is something is out of order.

Comment: Doubt it. Sounds like you're using TCP in some way, and tcp connections are being refused. Are you sure your two versions of the code are connecting the same way?

Comment: @MarcB : I didn't use `prepare()` in my connectivity test. The login info and `PDO()` was a direct copy/paste. After the connection bit, I have `$sql = "SOME SQL;";
 $dbRS = $dbh->query($sql);
 $row = empty($dbRS) ? false : $dbRS->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); print_r($row);` and it prints what I expect.

Comment: Interesting, never seen anyone bind a column before.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision : how else would you dynamically access different columns?

Comment: @Jacob: I wouldn't. I mostly use ORMs, and when I don't I hardcode column names within the sql. Not saying your approach is good or bad, just saying I never seen it before.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision : I barely know what ORM is, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: @Jacob: ORM = Object Relational Mapping. Basically introspects your schema and creates objects from tables, including relationships. There are two main players right now; Doctrine (http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and Propel (http://www.propelorm.org/). I would recommend Doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using vars that were not defined in the scope of the function. Simply use:

```
global $record_data;
```

as the first line in the function and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

- "Are mutually exclusive?": No, as you show, is a kind of "function declaration", and transaction is like a (OS) process where the function runs.
- "Are variables allowed?": I think  you must start checking your PHP function `record_data($q,$a,$k)`: there are a error. Try add `global $record_data;` at the begin of the function.

General comments: the main advantage of PDO is to capture errors (by PHP error line or returning SQL error messages) for **each** single SQL statment.
See [pdo.begintransaction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), [pdo.commit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php), [pdo.rollback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) and [pdo.error-handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).

Example:

```php
$dbh->beginTransaction();
/* Do SQL */
$sth1 = $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE xyz (..)");
$sth2 = record_data($qstn1,$ans1,$key1);
$sth2 = record_data($qstn2,$ans2,$key2);
/* Commit the changes */
$dbh->commit();
```